# Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Core.dll not found exception

Tags: xaml, xamarin, microsoft-speech-api

I'm developing hybrid xamarin forms application with cognitive services from microsoft azure on **.Net standard 2.0**. Got nuget packages of **CognitiveServices 0.1.0, Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech 1.3.1** along with **Xamarin.Forms 3.5.0**.

Nuget packages are updated to the latest. I'm running this on Win 7 machine from VS2017 IDE. Couldn't find any resources to resolve my exception. The solution builds successfully, but fails at runtime on genymotion emulator with `DllNotFoundException` in *Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll*.

[image: Exception screenshow]

Comment: I believe the Xamarin samples use the REST API, not a client library

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech SDK version 1.7.0 supports Xamarin (UWP, Android and iOS). Please try with that.

Answer (score -1):

The `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech` does not support Xamarin.Android|iOS. It does include Linux and Windows support that include native microphone/speaker support...

You might be looking for "Microsoft Cognitive Services" in which you have to roll your own native support for mic recording/streaming, etc....

- [Microsoft Cognitive Services Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/cognitive-services/)

#### Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech (see the runtime section)

```
.
├── build
│   ├── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.props
│   ├── REDIST.txt
│   ├── native
│   │   ├── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.targets
│   │   ├── Win32
│   │   │   └── Release
│   │   │       ├── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll
│   │   │       └── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.lib
│   │   ├── include
│   │   │   ├── c_api
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_audio_config.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_audio_stream.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_audio_stream_format.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_common.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_connection.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_error.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_factory.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_intent_recognizer.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_intent_result.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_intent_trigger.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_keyword_recognition_model.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_language_understanding_model.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_property_bag.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_recognizer.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_result.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_session.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_speech_config.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_translation_recognizer.h
│   │   │   │   ├── speechapi_c_translation_result.h
│   │   │   │   ├── spxdebug.h
│   │   │   │   └── spxerror.h
│   │   │   └── cxx_api
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_audio_config.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_audio_stream.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_audio_stream_format.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_common.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_connection.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_connection_eventargs.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_enums.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_eventargs.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_eventsignal.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_intent_recognition_eventargs.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_intent_recognition_result.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_intent_recognizer.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_intent_trigger.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_keyword_recognition_model.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_language_understanding_model.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_properties.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_recognition_async_recognizer.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_recognition_base_async_recognizer.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_recognition_eventargs.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_recognition_result.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_recognizer.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_session.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_session_eventargs.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_smart_handle.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_speech_config.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_speech_recognition_eventargs.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_speech_recognition_result.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_speech_recognizer.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_speech_translation_config.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_string_helpers.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_translation_eventargs.h
│   │   │       ├── speechapi_cxx_translation_recognizer.h
│   │   │       └── speechapi_cxx_translation_result.h
│   │   └── x64
│   │       └── Release
│   │           ├── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll
│   │           └── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.lib
│   └── net461
│       └── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.targets
├── lib
│   ├── net461
│   │   ├── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.dll
│   │   └── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.xml
│   ├── netstandard2.0
│   │   ├── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.dll
│   │   └── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.xml
│   └── uap10.0
│       ├── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.dll
│       └── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.xml
├── microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.1.3.1.nupkg
├── microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.1.3.1.nupkg.sha512
├── microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.nuspec
└── runtimes
    ├── linux-x64
    │   ├── lib
    │   │   └── netstandard2.0
    │   │       ├── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.dll
    │   │       └── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.xml
    │   └── native
    │       └── libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so
    ├── win-x64
    │   ├── native
    │   │   └── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll
    │   └── nativeassets
    │       └── uap
    │           └── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll
    └── win-x86
        ├── native
        │   └── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll
        └── nativeassets
            └── uap
                └── Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll
```